# How to cancel a task on Thread.Abort()

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I'm implementing a Method called by someone else. If my Method takes to long the caller will call `Thread.Abort()`. I start some tasks in my Method, and need to cancel those if my thread get aborted.

I currently guess the timeout I have and cancel the tasks after this timespan. It is not always the same timeout, depending on the operations executed before my method.

Are there a way to tie my tasks to that thread lifetime?

---

**Update**

To prevent any further comments, that I should not use `Thread.Abort()`, this is the code that handles the abort *(not called by me, can't change that)*:

```
        using (var cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                DoWork(cancelationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I use the `CancellationToken` not `Thread.Abort()`

Comment: You shouldn't use Thread.Abort as its a bad idea anyway to just kill a thread. Use cooperative cancelling using CancellationTokens which is the expected way how tasks should be aborted.

Comment: Tasks run on *separate* threads. Why call *Thread.Abort* though when using tasks? What does your code look like? You don't need Thread.Abort to implement timeouts, that's already provided by CancellationTokenSource, Task.Delay, various combinations

Comment: Even if you really need a thread, use a CancellationTokenSource to cancel the task *and* the thread cooperatively.

Comment: "I'm implementing a Method called by someone else" I have no control over this. For my Own methods I use CancellationTokens. But I can't change how I'm called.

Comment: Please never call `Thread.Abort()`. Even if you handle any exceptions it can still corrupt the run-time meaning that the remaining threads may not function correctly. It should only be used when forcing an application to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle ThreadAbortException to deal with cleanup, including aborting other threads if ncessary.

```
void MyThreadProc()
{
    try
    {
        //Do interesting things
    }
    catch ( ThreadAbortException e )
    {
        childThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought `ThreadAbortException` was a special exception that can't be catched. I rereded the documentation again, it says it is special and rethrow at the end of the catch. I now do the canceling in the finally block. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please never call `Thread.Abort()`. Even if you handle any exceptions it can still corrupt the run-time meaning that the remaining threads may not function correctly. It should only be used when forcing an application to close.